# Массивы node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
[2015-12-13 19:16:08.913] [DEBUG] result - { '1': '76561198188873209',
  '2': '76561198108244487',
  '3': '76561198240424734' }
```

Я имею вот такой вот массив. при попытки переработать его через forEach

```
users.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {

            });
```

Пишет что такого функции не существует. В чем проблема то?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что в javascript `{ ... }` это не массив. Это объект.

Один из способов обойти его:

```
for (var key in you_object) {
    console.log(key); // Выводим ключ
    console.log(you_object[key]); // Выводим значение
}
```